# Meaning of instanceof in Java

Tags: java, instanceof

I wrote below program but I am not able to understand the output.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[5];
        System.out.println(a instanceof Object);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, arrays are objects in Java. So it outputs true.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Now, I understand the concept of instanceof operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays, even if they're arrays of primitives, are objects, so the program outputs `true`.

Answer (score 0):

It will output True. Instanceof checks if the left one is from the class at the right of instanceof. Every class is subclass of Object class in Java so here it evaluates true.

Answer (score 0):

Besides checking class assignance, instanceof also check for the SuperClasses of the left side.

In your case the Array extends Object is a instanceof Object